# Probability of getting not two head consecutively on tossing a coin ten times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am working on this problem and found total number of favourable cases 144 as $$1 + 10 + \binom{9}{2}+ \binom{8}{3}+ \binom{7}{4}+ \binom{6}{5}$$ and answer in the book is 128 favourable cases (porbability = 128/1024). Where I am getting wrong?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: 144 is correct. You may also use the recurrence $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2),\; f(1)=2\; f(2)=3$

Comment: Hi; 144 is correct by direct count too.

Comment: How does the given formula work?  I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Rebecca which formula? One posted by OP. Or one giver by @gar?

Comment: The one by the OP.  But I think I know now (it's the same idea as my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/861111/91818).  If $i \geq 1$ heads in total, the first $i-1$ heads have a tails directly in front.  There are $\binom{n-(i-1)}{i}$ ways to achieve this, and $1+\sum_{i \geq 1} \binom{n-(i-1)}{i}$ in total.